# ConfigurationNotChecked error with Cppcheck

Tags: c, debugging, cppcheck

I checked my program with cppcheck with the following command.

```
cppcheck --enable=all --inconclusive --xml-version=2 --output-file=getopt.c.txt -v getopt.c
```

It gives me some ConfigurationNotChecked erros. I searched online but don't know what it means. Some errors are below.

```
    <error id="ConfigurationNotChecked" severity="information" msg="Skipping configuration &apos;__STDC__=0;const&apos; since the value of &apos;const&apos; is unknown. Use -D if you want to check it. You can use -U to skip it explicitly." verbose="Skipping configuration &apos;__STDC__=0;const&apos; since the value of &apos;const&apos; is unknown. Use -D if you want to check it. You can use -U to skip it explicitly.">
        <location file="getopt.c" line="194" column="0"/>
    </error>
    <error id="ConfigurationNotChecked" severity="information" msg="Skipping configuration &apos;__STDC__=0;const&apos; since the value of &apos;const&apos; is unknown. Use -D if you want to check it. You can use -U to skip it explicitly." verbose="Skipping configuration &apos;__STDC__=0;const&apos; since the value of &apos;const&apos; is unknown. Use -D if you want to check it. You can use -U to skip it explicitly.">
        <location file="getopt.c" line="208" column="0"/>
    </error>
    <error id="ConfigurationNotChecked" severity="information" msg="Skipping configuration &apos;__STDC__=0;const&apos; since the value of &apos;const&apos; is unknown. Use -D if you want to check it. You can use -U to skip it explicitly." verbose="Skipping configuration &apos;__STDC__=0;const&apos; since the value of &apos;const&apos; is unknown. Use -D if you want to check it. You can use -U to skip it explicitly.">
        <location file="getopt.c" line="317" column="0"/>
    </error>
```

It says use -D to check it. How can I use it with my command that i wrote above. I want to get information about what this error is. Also does my cppcheck command giving me all the possible errors that it can find or am i missing some argument.

Answer (score 1):

I am a Cppcheck developer. That is very weird. This sounds like a Cppcheck bug.

You should not use `-D` in this case.

Ideally I would like that you create a short code example that reproduce the problem. Maybe you can extract some code in getopt.c around line 190 and see if you still get such information message.

Answer (score 0):

The manpage describes this

```
       -D<id>
           By default Cppcheck checks all configurations. Use -D to limit the checking. When -D is used the checking is limited to the given configuration. Example: -DDEBUG=1
           -D__cplusplus
```